# ¿ n is not a type?

Tags: c++

tengo el siguiente archivo .h pero cuando lo compilo me sale este error, investigue y es como si declarara a n como un tipo de dato,tambien intente poner la variable como const,pero no me deja porque es un vector,quiero solucionar este error.

includes.h:33:37: error: 'n' is not a type

```
  #include "heders.h"
    using namespace std;
    
    int n  = 208648;
    
    char NOMBRE_ARCHIVO[] = "IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.csv"; 
    FILE *p = fopen(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO,"r");
    
    
    struct values{
    
     string Stringline;
     int unsigned lowerValue;
     int unsigned higherValue;
     string country;
        
     };
    
    struct vectors{
        
    
      vector<int unsigned> lowersValues(n); 
      vector<int unsigned> highersValues(n);
      vector<string> code_countrys(n);
        
     };
```

Comment: Declara ```n``` como ```size_type```.

Comment: Es decir,  ```size_t```

Answer (score 0):

En un struct, las variables solo se declaran y opcionalmente las puedes inicializar en la misma línea. Sería así:

```
struct vectors{
    vector<int unsigned> lowersValues; 
    vector<int unsigned> highersValues;
    vector<string> code_countrys;
};
```

Por defecto, si no se inicializan el constructor sin parámetros es llamado. Para inicializarlos, puedes hacerlo así:

```
struct vectors{
    vector<int unsigned> lowersValues = vector<int unsigned>(n); 
    vector<int unsigned> highersValues = vector<int unsigned>(n);
    vector<string> code_countrys = vector<string>(n);
};
```

En este caso, otra opción es reservar memoria explícitamente desde el constructor del struct:

```
vectors(){
    lowersValues.reserve(n);
    highersValues.reserve(n);
    code_countrys.reserve(n);
}
```

Lo que sucede es que al declarar las variables del modo que lo estás haciendo, el compilador supone que quieres una función. Entonces como antes del nombre del parámetro escribes su tipo, obtienes el error de que `n` no es un tipo.